# Using Modulus to loop through

Tags: javascript, loops

I've been stuck on this last part of my assignment for the longest time. I'm trying to loop through the alphabet using modulus. delta is the number of letters you have to move forward or backwards to get the real letter. SO if given getchars("H",-2), the function is supposed to return F. A problem arises however if the chars.charAt(chars.getIndexOf(data.charAt(i))) ever equals a number less than 0. I want to be able to give my function ("A", -1) or any negative number and have it return "Z".

This is an assignment for class so if possible please keep it to just modulus. I've been working on this last part for like 2 hours now.

```
function getChars(data,delta)
{
    var chars;
    var i;
    var foundAt;
    var newString;

    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    data = data.toUpperCase();
    delta = Math.min(chars.length, delta);
    i = 0;
    newString = "";

    while (i < data.length)
    {
        if(delta <= 0)
        {
            foundAt = (chars.indexOf(data.charAt(i)) + delta)  ;window.alert(foundAt)
            //newString = newString + chars.charAt(foundAt);
            //i = i + 1;
        }
        else if((chars.indexOf(data.charAt(i)) < 0))
        {
            foundAt = data.charAt(i);
            newString = newString + foundAt;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
        foundAt = ((chars.indexOf(data.charAt(0 + i)) + delta)) % chars.length;window.alert(foundAt);
        newString = newString + chars.charAt(foundAt);window.alert(newString);
        i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    //return newString;
}
```

Comment: Simple if statement - You have 26 letters. if letter_ID < 0, letter_ID = 25. (25 because js has 0 index)

Comment: why do you need a while loop? can't you just work out the index of the letter and then add the delta then take the modulus?

Answer (score 0):

To be flexible, you can use `i = chars.length - 1;` and first after that do the `found at`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use you own [modulus function](http://javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm) :

```
function modulus(n,m) {
    return ((n%m)+m)%m;
};
```

With your following code :

```
function getChars(data,delta)
{
    var chars;
    var i;
    var foundAt;
    var newString;

    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    data = data.toUpperCase();
    i = 0;
    newString = "";

    while (i < data.length)
    {
        newString += chars.charAt(modulus(chars.indexOf(data[i])+delta,26))
        i++;
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this part : modulus(chars.indexOf(data[i])+delta,26)

Comment: `chars.indexOf(data[i])` returns the index of your `data[i]`character in your `chars` list. And we add the delta, and then we calcultate the modulus with 26 to get a number between 0 and 25

Comment: I'm sorry but we have not learned lists yet so I'm not familiar with them. Is there anyway to just pass chars.indexOf(data(i))? I'm asking because I tried and failed.

Comment: Where do you have the problem ?